# SwipeJS - Adding Margin/Padding between Swipable Elements

Tags: jquery, css, swipe

(Working with SwipeJS plugin by Brad Birdsall : https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe)

I was playing around and trying to add 'padding' around the flickable cards, since right now they are all squeezed into one big pack. (Here's what it looks like when swiping from one card to another. I'd like to see some padding between these cards)

[image: Screen Shot 2013-04-28 at 8 32 20 PM]

I've even added a supplemental div wrapping the card divs thinking the width would be calculated on the div that's a direct child to .slide-wrap, as such:

```
<div id='slider' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
    <div class="card-wrap"><div class="card"></div></div>
    <div class="card-wrap"><div class="card"></div></div>
    <div class="card-wrap"><div class="card"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've hacked my way through the script, but it only really works halfway and I am sure there is a much simpler answer. Any padding/margin configurations directly in SwipeJS? Am I missing something?

Thanks! and awesome plugin!

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution by chance?